# Want to display notification in Task pane in Word using VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word, notifications, office-addins, customtaskpane

I have coded a VBA macro that notifies me whenever a new comment has been added to a document using a MsgBox.

I now require that no notification should be in the form of a MsgBox but are displayed in a task pane by clicking on the custom button(Comment Notifier) on the ribbon of word.

Can you suggest me  way to do this?

Comment: Task Panes are a feature of VSTO and the newer Office Web Add-ins, not VBA.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to migrate your existing VBA solution to the add-in rails. There is no way to create a task pane from VBA. The [Walkthrough: Create your first VSTO Add-in for Word](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/walkthrough-creating-your-first-vsto-add-in-for-word?view=vs-2022#:%7E:text=To%20create%20a%20new%20Word%20VSTO%20Add%2Din%20project%20in%20Visual%20Studio&text=In%20the%20templates%20pane%2C%20expand,Word%20VSTO%20Add%2Din%20project.) article explains how to get started quickly. After adding all event handlers to the add-in you may add a task pane to the add-in project, see [How to: Add a custom task pane to an application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/how-to-add-a-custom-task-pane-to-an-application?view=vs-2022) for more information.

Finally, the [Walkthrough: Synchronize a custom task pane with a Ribbon button](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/walkthrough-synchronizing-a-custom-task-pane-with-a-ribbon-button?view=vs-2022) explains how to automate a task pane by clicking on the ribbon button, so you just need to replace the source code a bit and display a notification on the task pane instead.